# Erro ao insertar Múltiplas Linhas PHP + PDO + POSTGRESQL

Tags: php, pdo, postgresql

Estou utilizando o multiple insert, mas os caracteres internos do texto tem feito o insert falhar. Usei o método addslaches na string mas o erro permanece, alguma sugestão do que posso fazer para contornar?

Tenho o seguinte código

```
  private function GetPostsNews($token,$secret,$fields)
{
    $this->pack = json_decode($this->getToken($token,$secret,$fields), true);

    if(count($this->pack)<25)
    {$updated = 0;}
    else{$updated=1;}

    foreach($this->pack as $key => $value):
        if(!isset($value['picture'])) :  $value['picture'] = 'imagem/post.jpg' ; endif ;
        if(!isset($value['message'])) : $value['message']  = 'imagem incorporada' ; endif ;           
        if(!isset($value['permalink_url'])) : $value['permalink_url'] = 'not a link set' ; endif ;            
        if(!isset($value['name'])) : $value['name'] = 'not a name set' ; endif ;

        $idpost = $value['id'];
        $ps_idpage = $this->guide[0];
        $ps_date = \TimeConver::GMTtoUTC($value['created_time']['date'], "Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ps_categoty = $value['type'];
        $ps_picture = $value['picture']; 
        $ps_name = $value['name'];
        $ps_message = addslashes($value['message']);
        $ps_link = $value['permalink_url'];
        $sent = new \sentimentalization($idpost,$ps_date,'FB_POST',$ps_message);
        $wordcloud = new \wordcloud($idpost,'FB_POST',$ps_message);


        $this->values.= "('{$idpost}','{$ps_idpage}','{$ps_date}','{$ps_categoty}','{$ps_picture}','{$ps_name}','{$ps_message}','{$ps_link}'), " ;

        $ps = new Executor();        
        $ps->PostSummary($idpost)->CollectPostSummary();
    endforeach;

    $insert = new \insert();
    $insert->InsertMultiplePost($this->values);
```

ai no CRUD tenho

```
  public function insertmultiple($fields,$values){  
    // Atribui a instrução SQL construida no método   
    $sql = $this->buildInsertMultiple($fields, $values);

    // Passa a instrução para o PDO   
    $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);    

    // Executa a instrução SQL e captura o retorno   
    $retorno = $stm->execute();}
```

e

```
private function buildInsertmultiple($campos, $values){   

       // Inicializa variáveis   
       //$sql = "";   
       //$campos = "";   
       //$valores = "";   

       // Loop para montar a instrução com os campos e valores   

       // Retira vírgula do final da string   

       // Retira vírgula do final da string   
       $values = (substr($values, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($values, 0, (strlen($values) - 2))) : $values ;    

       // Concatena todas as variáveis e finaliza a instrução   
       $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->tabela}" . $campos . "VALUES" . $values ; 

       var_dump($sql);  

       // Retorna string com instrução SQL   
       return trim($sql);   
   }
```

o log me retorna o seguinte erro:
< 2016-08-22 12:03:55.490 BRT >ERROR:  syntax error at or near "O" at character 148
< 2016-08-22 12:03:55.490 BRT >STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO reduce_word_recurrency(_id, rwr_id, rwr_type,rwr_word) VALUES('201608221208580.090165' , '109597815616_10154194837525617','FB_POST','\'O' ), ('201608221208$
< 2016-08-22 12:03:56.439 BRT >ERROR:  syntax error at or near "não" at character 1045
< 2016-08-22 12:03:56.439 BRT >STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO reduce_word_recurrency(_id, rwr_id, rwr_type,rwr_word) VALUES('201608221208590.038443' , '109597815616_10154191786040617','FB_POST','Jornal' ), ('201608221$
< 2016-08-22 12:04:12.461 BRT >ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Com" at character 1648
< 2016-08-22 12:04:12.461 BRT >STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO fb_post(idpost,ps_idpage,ps_date,ps_categoty,ps_picture,ps_name,ps_message,ps_link)VALUES(....

Comment: Christopher, por favor edite sua pergunta, incluindo o código que você já tem para que possamos lhe auxiliar da melhor forma possível.

Comment: Coloquei Bruno Bermann o que tenho usado nas classes, obrigado!